# Importing CSV files in DIVA-GIS

Tags: csv, diva-gis, gbif

I have a CSV text file which i got from GBIF containing a species distribution.
How would I arrange it so that I could display it in DIVA GIS?

Answer (score 1):

Use function **Import Points to Shapefile** from text file - `Data --> Import Points to Shapefile --> From text file`

[image]

Than set input and output file path, field delimiter is *Tab*. Set coordinates columns - coordinates in GBIF csv are stored in columns `decimallongitude` and `decimallatitude`. Hit *Apply*.

[image]

Note: Since shapefiles has 10 character limit of field name, you will see some pop-ups noting this. Don't worry to proceed, filed names will by automatically shortened.